# angularjs removed my form attribute when nav-tabs clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I dont really know angularjs. But this frontend from my client.
**My form attribute was removed when i click nav-tabs**.

**actionTry="0"** is attribute for ajax load status
i dont know, is this the main issue or there is another thing, because i try to add **actionTry="0"** manually after clicked **nav-tabs**. and Booom ! Nothing happend 
-_-

i dont really know angluarjs. please let me know the solution.

For example, this is my first load form html :

```
<form class="formSetting" actionForm="bookClass" actionTry="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="idSchedule" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="tanggalSchedule" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="returnPage" value="">
    <button class="btn btn-blue3">RESERVE ACTIVITY</button>
</form>
```

but when i clicked the nav-tabs, **actionTry="0" was removed**.

```
<form class="formSetting" actionForm="bookClass">
    <input type="hidden" name="idSchedule" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="tanggalSchedule" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="returnPage" value="">
    <button class="btn btn-blue3">RESERVE ACTIVITY</button>
</form>
```

here is the video : [Google Drive Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Z-CEFXF7zBTzRITDdEMHI0QnM/view?usp=sharing)

If you want to test it. You can visit the online version : [Online Version](https://m.fitaccess.co.id/studio-211/class-1463/schedule-5538/2016-09-29/Fitness)

```
E-Mail : dev@stackoverflow.com
Password : testtest
```

Please help me guys.

Thanks before :)